# kotlin create a Fragment,got a error like this:

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

When I create a `fragment`:

```
class DetailListFragment(siteId: Int, channelId: Int) : BaseFragment() {

private var mSiteId: Int
private var mChannelId: Int

init {
    this.mSiteId = siteId
    this.mChannelId = channelId
}

override fun getLayoutId(): Int {
}

override fun initView() {
}

override fun initData() {
}}
```

I getting a compile error like this:

```
This Fragment should provide a default constructor(a public constructor with no arguments)
```

How can I deal with this issue?
How can I declare a number of constructors in Kotlin?

Comment: You need to set default values for your private members (default c'tor)

Comment: Apart from the question, from the documentation `BaseFragment` is deprecated use `BaseSupportFragment`

Answer (score 0):

The error says that there is no "parameter-less" constructors available (*an empty constructor*) for this fragment and the system couldn't be able to recreate this fragment when configuration changes occur.

You **shouldn't** use constructor to pass parameters to the fragment.

You **should** (I mean you must) use arguments approach to pass parameters to the `fragment`.

Like this:

```
class DetailListFragment : BaseFragment() {

    companion object {
        fun create(siteId: Int, channelId: Int):DetailListFragment {
            return DetailListFragment().apply {
                 arguments = Bundle()
                 arguments?.putInt("siteId", siteId)
                 arguments?.putInt("channelId", channelId)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedState:Bundle) {
         mSiteId = arguments?.getInt("siteId") ?: 0
         mChannelId= arguments?.getInt("channelId") ?: 0
    }
}
```